# Where can I find a g++ 4.7 package?

Tags: 11.10, ppa, g++

Some time ago, I managed to find PPA featuring g++-4.7 build. However, I had to reinstall everything on my machine and I lost name of that PPA. Could anyone point me to it? I tried to find it again, but without any luck. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 installation.

Comment: I strongly recommend you do not install 4.7 in place of gcc that is with your version.  If you do, you run the risk of breaking your system.

Comment: @ThomasWard: I know, I am not a complete newbie.

Comment: @Griwes, you may not be a 'newbie' but others might be and his observation is correct.

Comment: [Related.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240919/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-on-lubuntu-11-10) (But *if* we decide that's a duplicate of this, we should make sure to ask for answers to be merged, as that's about what to do when this doesn't work.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Toolchain test builds PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test) contains many packages including gcc-4.7.

You can add the repository using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Then, to install it use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.7
```

To change the default compiler use update-alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Comment: Did not work for me. I only see gcc-4.6 (on ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: Worked with ubuntu 12.04

Comment: How can I uninstall g++-4.6 without uninstalling g++ ? Currently I have packages `g++`, `g++-4.6` and `g++-4.7` installed. as result `g++ --version` gives me version 4.6.

Comment: Ah perhaps I need simply rename g++-4.7 to g++

Comment: sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a PPA for g++-4.7 but there is a gcc-snapshot package.

I guess you have to compile it yourself:
http://www.lukaszbyczynski.com/archives/208

Comment: Well, I cannot find it now, but I recall doing `apt-get install g++-4.7 gcc-4.7`...

Answer (score 0):

See http://ask.debian.net/questions/backporting-more-recent-versions-of-the-gcc-toolchain-to-debian-stable

for my description of backporting gcc 4.7 to Debian stable.