# How to upgrade g++ to 4.7.1?

Tags: upgrade, gcc, g++

Richard Holloway's answer to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76885/where-can-i-find-a-g-4-7-package) nicely explains how to upgrade from 4.6.3 to 4.7.0 (on 12.04, in my case) but I would like to upgrade to 4.7.1, which has been available for awhile.  However there is no package `g++-4.7.1` and I don't know otherwise how to do it, does anyone else?

Comment: [How to install and use GCC g++ v4.7 and C++11 on Ubuntu 12.04](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/).

Comment: @lammilind Does this install 4.7.1?  Looks like it's 4.7.0 instructions.

Comment: @MattPhllips, now better to install 4.8.0. Above link illustrates the process. You should change the version number according to need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, this was excruciating. Here's how I did it (NB, for a 32-bit system):

1. $sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
2. $sudo apt-get install m4
3. Download [mpfr](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/#download), configure, make, make install
4. Download [gmp](http://gmplib.org/), configure, make, make install
5. Download [mpc](http://www.multiprecision.org/index.php?prog=mpc&page=download), configure, make, make install
6. In order to compensate for insufficient path information, added this to .bashrc

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu export
>
> export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu export
>
> export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu

the former I got from [here](http://samritmaity.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/cannot-compute-suffix-of-object-files-gcc-4-4-3-installation-problem-solved/) and the latter from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-02/msg00314.html), modified appropriately for my install locations.

.7. Add these symlinks for the same reason:

> $sudo ln -s /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-32.h /usr/include/gnu
>
> $sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/crti.o
>
> $sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/crt1.o
>
> $sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o /usr/lib/crtn.o
>
> $sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmpc.so.3
>   /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3

.8. Download g++-4.7.1, configure, make, make install

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile g++-4.7.1

List of mirrors:

http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html

Select mirror, click releases and search for gcc-4.7.1.

Download source, and compile.

Comment: Thanks, working on it--looks like there's a lot of dependencies to wade through first so it might be awhile.

Comment: Well, after installing gmp, mpc, and mpfr as well as gcc-multilib (to get rid of an error arising because the compiler couldn't find `bits/predefs.h`), now the compiler can't find `gnu/stubs-32.h`.  The weird thing is that this seems to be a problem when compiling in 32 bit mode on a 64-bit system--however I'm doing this on a 32-bit laptop.  `apt-file` says this is part of the `libc6-dev` package, but I already have the newest version installed...